# React Native button text disappears in release APK

Tags: android, css, react-native

On my debug APK the text on my buttons appears fine, however when I create the release APK and run it on the exact same phone as I was debugging from... the text that appeared on the buttons in the debug doesn't appear in the release APK.

I'm using a 5' Samsung for debugging and testing. I don't know what the issue is, considering I'm not changing anything between release and debug versions. And I don't think styling should be affected. Any ideas what the issue is? Is my font size too large even though it shows in the debug version?

The following is my code for the buttons I'm using:

```
class LoginButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.label = ""
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight
         style={styles.button1}
         onPress={this.props.onPress}
        >
         <Text style = {{fontSize: 20, color:'#24572c',}} > {this.props.label} </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class CreateAccountButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.label = ""
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight
         style={styles.button2}
         onPress={this.props.onPress}
        >
         <Text style = {{fontSize: 20, color:'white',}} > {this.props.label} </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In the main screen component these the buttons instances:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style= {styles.background}
          source = {require('../FinalSlices/Slices/signin/splashbackground.jpg')}
          />
        {/*<Image source = {require('./FinalSlices/Slices/home/banner.png')} style = {styles.bannerImage}/>*/}
        <View>
          <View style={styles.top} >
            <Image source = {require('../FinalSlices/Slices/signin/logo.png')} style = {styles.logo}/>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <View style={styles.spacer}>
                <LoginButton label='Sign In' onPress={this._onLoginPress.bind(this)} />
                <CreateAccountButton label= 'Create Account' onPress={this._onCreateAccountPress.bind(this)} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.spacer}>
          </View>

          </View>
        </View>

      </View>
```

And these are the relevant CSS styles:

```
bottom: {
      flex: 1,
      marginTop:20,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    button1: {

        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 15,
        borderColor: 'white',
        width: 250,
        height: 50,
    },
    button2: {
        backgroundColor: '#24572c',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 15,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'white',
        width: 250,
        height: 50,
    },
    spacer: {
        flex: 1,
        // backgroundColor: 'pink',
    },
```

Comment: as a side-note: `props` are read-only, so declaration `this.props.label = ""` is invalid.

Comment: could that be the issue or it wouldn't affect the app and just be ignored ?